# Rhythmbox error while saving song information: Could not multiplex stream

Tags: audio, rhythmbox

I play a lot of `.ra` or `.rm` files in Rhythmbox. It plays fine but when I try to edit with the property box it says:

> Error while saving song information
> Could not multiplex stream.

But it works fine with other file types.

My system is Mint 12 (32bit) with Cinnamon desk top, and 2.90.1 Rhythmbox 2.90.1

Answer (score 0):

In Rhythmbox 3.4.2 on Linux Mint I get

```
Error while saving song information
Internal data stream error
```

I help myself by lossless conversion of all files in the directory, e.g. from `.aac` to `.m4a`

To do so,

- `cd` to the directory
- run

```
find . -exec ffmpeg -i {} -acodec copy {}.m4a \;
```